# Comparing best and average-time complexities

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

True or False: The best case time complexity of an algorithm with a worst case complexity of O(n^2) is better than the average-case of an algorithm with a worst-case of O(n^3).

I'm studying for a final exam and I came across this question. I feel like the obvious answer is yes, but I haven't been able to find evidence because I cannot find a good cubic time algorithm. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: No, the obvious answer is "no". The best case is no worse than the average case which is no worse than the worst case. That's all you can assert about their relationship. Any stringer statement would be false.

Comment: You can create your own convoluted algorithm to get an example. There is no need for a 'well-known' algorithm to disprove this statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False.

The former might have a best case of O(n^2) while the latter might have an average case of O(n). Neither the best or average cases necessarily relate to the worst.